# Merging 3 databases with same names, and renaming them in python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, merge, rename

I have 3 df with 25 columns each. All the columns are same in the 3 df.

I want to merge the 3 df, and change the column name to "_a" for 25 columns of df1, change to "_b" for 25 columns of df2, and change to "_c" for 25 columns of df3.

I am using the below code:

```
pd.merge(pd.merge(df1,df2,'left',on='year',suffixes=['_a','_b']),df3,'left',on='year')
```

How do I use a rename or some other function, to change all the 25 columns of df3 in the code above?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
pd.merge(pd.merge(df1,df2,'left',on='year',suffixes=['_a','_b']),
         df3,'left',on='year',suffixes=['','_c'])
```

---

Another approach:

Source DFs:

```
In [68]: d1
Out[68]:
   col1  col2  col3
0     1     2     3
1     4     5     6

In [69]: d2
Out[69]:
   col1  col2  col3
0    11    12    13
1    14    15    16

In [70]: d3
Out[70]:
   col1  col2  col3
0    21    22    23
1    24    25    26
```

Let's create a list of DFs:

```
In [71]: dfs = [d1,d2,d3]
```

and a list of suffixes:

```
In [73]: suffixes = ['_a','_b','_c']
```

Now we can merge them in one step like as follows:

```
In [74]: pd.concat([df.add_suffix(suffixes[i]) for i,df in enumerate(dfs)], axis=1)
Out[74]:
   col1_a  col2_a  col3_a  col1_b  col2_b  col3_b  col1_c  col2_c  col3_c
0       1       2       3      11      12      13      21      22      23
1       4       5       6      14      15      16      24      25      26
```

Short explanation: in the list comprehension we are generating a list of DFs with already renamed columns:

```
In [75]: [suffixes[i] for i,df in enumerate(dfs)]
Out[75]: ['_a', '_b', '_c']

In [76]: [df.add_suffix(suffixes[i]) for i,df in enumerate(dfs)]
Out[76]:
[   col1_a  col2_a  col3_a
 0       1       2       3
 1       4       5       6,    col1_b  col2_b  col3_b
 0      11      12      13
 1      14      15      16,    col1_c  col2_c  col3_c
 0      21      22      23
 1      24      25      26]
```

Comment: Great demonstration, even before the edit! [List Comprehensions](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) are often confusing to those new to python, so they generally deserve a small explanation or note. Nonetheless, your answer is clear and concise. +1

Comment: Thanks!   pd.merge(pd.merge(df1,df2,'left',on='year',suffixes=['_a','_b']),
         df3,'left',on='year',suffixes=['','_c']) does not work as I guess the columns of the data frames should be identical (Note- merging 2 dfs changes the columns to "_a" and "_b" and so they are not identical to df3. How can I use a rename function to change the suffix of the 3rd df?

Comment: maybe you can try `reduce(lambda x, y: pd.merge(x, y, on = 'year'), l)`

Comment: @Wen, it’s a great idea- turn it into an answer.

Comment: concat is a bad idea... This is not the same than if you merge on a specific column and you may have unexpected results.